# Add/Remove dynamic textfields on click of a button/link using form builder in symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig, formbuilder

This is how my interface should look like.

[image]

So can any one suggest this using form builder in Symfony2 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start from the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) and look at [AcmePizzaBundle](https://github.com/beberlei/AcmePizzaBundle). That's all you need.